# Registering post type doesn't show results on front-end

Tags: custom-post-types

I followed the same codes in a tutorial but my codes does show any results while echoing. 
below is my nightmare:

```
  // Note Post Type <br>
  register_post_type('note', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Notes',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Note',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Note',
      'all_items' => 'All Notes',
      'singular_name' => 'Note'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog'
  ));


// section to echo out the result.


<div class="container container--narrow page-section">
  <ul class="min-list link-list" id="my-notes">
   <?php 
    $userNotes = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'note',
     'author' => get_current_user_id()
          ));

while($userNotes->have_posts()) {
$userNotes->the_post(); ?>
 <li>
<input class="note-title-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
 <span class="edit-note"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</span>
 <span class="delete-note"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</span>
 <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
 </li>
 <?php }    
    ?>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: You indicated that you were following a tutorial. Could you link to that tutorial so others who might potentially answer could take a look at the expected result and compare with what you've got here?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

```
/**
 * Register a custom post type called "book".
 *
 * @see get_post_type_labels() for label keys.
 */
function wpdocs_codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Books', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Book', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Books', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Book', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Book', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Books:', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No books found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( 'Book Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives'              => _x( 'Book archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into book', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this book', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter books list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Books list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list'            => _x( 'Books list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_codex_book_init' );
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not solve my issue

Comment: I have written the above code. but when I want to output the results to the front-page. it shows no results. There is no logical reason for this,

Comment: Any solution would be most appreciated, thanks

Comment: are you can add code which you used it for fetch posts in front ?

Comment: <?php 
          $userNotes = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'note',
            'author' => get_current_user_id()
          ));

          while($userNotes->have_posts()) {
            $userNotes->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
              <input value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
              <span><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</span>
              <span><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</span>
              <textarea><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea></li>
          <?php }

Comment: above is the whole code all together

Comment: have tried to add `author` in `supports` ?

Comment: no I have not tried author in supports. but supports is in another file where register_post_type is. but author is in another folder where i want to get the content

Comment: no I have not tried author in supports. but supports is in another file where register_post_type is. but author is in another folder where i want to get the content

Comment: author should be in here because i want to get the content of a specific author

Comment: Dear Abdo-Host, I found a new thing. if i delete the 'author' => get_current_user_id() from code, it works quite fine and show the results. but that is not exactly what i want. because the notes content that i want to get is not the same for all authors. every author will have different notes that is why i need their id to show them their specific notes. Now I am confused why the content does not show when adding the author id ? !!!!

Comment: hi once again. thanks a lot. you were right. when i moved the get_current_user_id to supports, my problem solved. now i have a new issue. when i get the content and want to display them in textarea; it shows the extra notes around the text by wordpress. do you know how to remove them?

Comment: this is the issue:                                                                                                                              <!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>this is biology #1 from admin account</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->1

Comment: i donot want the <p> tag and i dont want the extra comment from wordpress